# Do something when my app's notification is triggered

Tags: android

I'd like an activity of my app to listen when a specific notification is received and do something then.

The notification is triggered from within the app itself. I'm kind of new to Android development (and to development in general) so here's some pseudocode for what I want to do:

```
Activity{
   notificationListener(){
      if(notification is received){
         //Do something
      }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) of `Notification`, there seems no way to listen to sending `Notification`. After thinking deep, you would understand why we can't. AFAYK, it is we that write codes to send `Notification` but not the system, right? We surely know when we send `Notification`s, right? So, if you want to know when `Notification` is sent, why not do something, like sending `BroadcastReceiver` or starting `Service` to let other codes noticed? It all depends on our code-writers. And here is how to customize a Notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```